# Trouble understanding allObjects() in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm making an app that uses Realm as the offline database. Problem is that when I call `Workout.allObjects()`, nothing shows up. I did some debugging and found the results below

**Relevant Code**

```
class Workout: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var exercises: RLMArray = RLMArray(objectClassName: "Exercise")
    dynamic var numberOfWorkouts = 0

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}


func createWorkoutObject() {
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    try! realm.transactionWithBlock {
        workout = Workout()
    }
}
```

At the end of `createWorkoutObject()` (with a breakpoint), I ran
[image]

So there is obviously a Workout object, but `Workout.allObjects()` doesn't seem to see it.

Why is this? I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allObjects()` method only returns objects that are managed by the given Realm. In `createWorkoutObject()` you create an instance of `Workout`, but do not add it to the Realm. Since this new object is not managed by the Realm, `allObjects()` will not return it.

Try:

```
func createWorkoutObject() {
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    try! realm.transactionWithBlock {
        workout = Workout()
        realm.addObject(workout)
    }
}
```

Comment: Right!! I had a feeling I was missing something, totally forgot about this. Thanks!

Comment: I have a question related to this. If I don't call realm.addObject(object), does that object get deleted when the view deallocates or is it persistent in some weird place in Realm? I have a hunch it gets deleted but wanted to ask

Comment: If you don't call `addObject` then your object has the same lifetime as any other Swift or Objective-C object, and will be deallocated when there are no remaining strong references to it.